# using shell.openItem() to open a file in an asar archive

Tags: node.js, electron

I have an electron app that uses an app.asar file.  I want to be able to open files (.xlsx) that are in the asar file in the default Windows application (which is Excel).  I have tried

```
let xlsx = path.join(__dirname + '/path/to/app.asar/path/to/file');
shell.openItem(xlsx);
```

but it doesn't work (no error, the file doesn't open).

I can read the file with fs

```
let xlsx = path.join(__dirname + '/path/to/app.asar/path/to/file');
fs.readFileSync(xlsx);
```

but I can't get the file to open in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [Application Packaging](https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/application-packaging/)

> An asar archive is a simple tar-like format that concatenates files into a single file. Electron can read arbitrary files from it without unpacking the whole file.

Only Electron can access those files, Excel and other applications simply can not deal with asar archives.

You could copy the file from the asar archive to the system's temp folder and open it from there. Like this:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const {shell, app} = require('electron')

let xlsx = path.join(__dirname,'/path/to/app.asar/path/to/file')
let xlsxtmp = üath.join(app.getPath('temp', 'file')
let ws = fs.createWriteStream(xlsxtmp)

fs.createReadStream(xlsx).pipe(ws)

ws.on('finish', () => {
    shell.openItem(xlsxtmp);
}
```

Another option would be to not pack that xlsx into the archive and instead download it into the `userData` path.

Comment: That worked, thank you!  I just have to make a couple tweaks: `let xlsx = path.join(__dirname + '/path/to/file')` and `let xlsxtmp = path.join(app.getPath('temp'),'file')`.  I also found out that `__dirname` resolves to `C:\path\to\app\resources\app.asar` and not just `C:\path\to\app`  That really threw me off for awhile.